# Visual studio 2017 разработка для android ошибка

Tags: c#, visual-studio

> Ошибка    CS1504  Не удалось открыть исходный файл
>   "C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\PacMan\PacMan\Game.cs" — Была сделана попытка загрузить
>   программу, имеющую неверный формат. (Исключение из HRESULT:
>   0x8007000B).  PacMan  C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\PacMan\PacMan\CSC   1   Активный

Выдает ошибку и не запускает проект . как можно исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте поменять платформу для сборки(х64, х86 etc.)

Comment: Тут есть кажется решение на твой трабл...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d580h1k(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: У меня все сборки x86 вообще нет x64. В диспетчере sdk пакетов все x86 .  
Попробуйте поменять платформу для сборки(х64, х86 etc.)